# How to create a virtual directory from file in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8, virtual-directory

I want to import virtual directory setting via file in IIS 8.5, but cannot find an option to do so. In IIS 6 you can:

> Right click on the site **->** New **->** Virtual Directory (From File)

I do not see this option in IIS 8.5, only an option to 'Add Virtual Directory...'

Google is not helping today. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to do this similar to how you can in IIS 6, maybe there is a powershell command...

However, I did find a way to add sites via the applicationHost.config file, which is usually located at: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. (be sure to make a back up of the file in case you make a booboo).

Since I have similar sites and apps, it is was easy to copy and paste, and modify the necessary fields.

You can add sites and app pools in the section:

```
<system.applicationHost>
```

App Pools:

```
<applicationPools>
...
```

Sites:

```
<sites>
```

If you have applications under a site then there has to be a corresponding location node:

```
 <location path="Default Web Site/yoursiteapp">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
                <access sslFlags="None" />
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```